# Сохранение последнего билда (версии)

Tags: java

Есть задача добавить в версию проекта запись вида:

```
build yyyymmdd.HHmm
```

Когда я делаю билд проекта, в шапке программы отображается, к примеру:

```
build 20180710.1110
```

После упаковки программы в инсталлятор, пользователь накатывает программу и запускает, он видит, например:

```
build 20180711.0930
```

И каждый раз, когда он будет запускать заново приложение, версия будет обновляться с текущей датой и временем, что логично. Мой вопрос такой: **как сделать сохранение последнего билда проекта автоматически, без последующего обновления?** Вариант править руками не подходит.

Дополнение:

Использую плагин Maven - buildnumber-maven-plugin. Получилось создать файл .properties, в который записывается номер билда, каждый раз увеличивающийся на 1. Но мне необходимо сделать то же самое с датой, не могу вывести текущую дату. Подскажите, как подкорректировать плагин.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>buildnumber</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>

                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <format>${project.version};{0,number}</format>
                <items>
                    <item>buildNumber</item>
                </items>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <!--<revisionOnScmFailure>unknownbuild</revisionOnScmFailure>-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: а через что вы билдите? в gradle можно это сделать достаточно легко

Comment: Maven. Если скажете как - буду признателен

Comment: а откуда вы изначально берете версию? где она хранится?

Comment: На данный момент она просто записана в переменной. Мой метод прибавляет к ней build yyyymmdd.HHmm